# PEAR DB Error: no such table

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, pear

I am using Google Maps PHP API which uses PEAR. I am getting the DB Error: no such table. I am not sure what to do ? I have checked the DB parameters like DB Name, Table Name. Everything seems correct.

The following code is giving the error:

```
$MAP_OBJECT->addMarkerByAddress($address,$address /*marker title*/, "", $tooltip=$address, $filename= $mapMarkerSmall);
```

Comment: Could you provide the code in question?

Comment: The below is the function that is giving the error :                   $MAP_OBJECT->addMarkerByAddress($address,$address /*marker title*/, "", $tooltip=$address, $filename= $mapMarkerSmall);   This is the function from Google Maps PHP Api

Comment: Actually the codes runs fine on my local PC. I am using XAMPP as my local PHP development environment. Now the problem has occurred when I uploaded my code to hostgator.com web host. I have taken the issue with them and they have installed PEAR and its extension like DB module etc.

Answer (score 0):

After wasting so much time about the above error, I finally found that I was using the table name in Upper Case while on my remote host/server the table name was in lower case. So I changed my table name to lower case letters in my code and the error just vanished :)

It is real creepy, as far as I know that SQL is case insensitive but I guess PEAR is case sensitive :)